# Struct pointer to access register on microcontroller?

Tags: c, arm, cortex-m, cmsis

I'm trying to understand the cmsis header file included with the STM-32 Cortex-M4 microcontroller.
They have a struct that is

```
typedef struct
{
  __IO uint32_t MODER;    /*!< GPIO port mode register,               Address offset: 0x00      */
  __IO uint32_t OTYPER;   /*!< GPIO port output type register,        Address offset: 0x04      */
  __IO uint32_t OSPEEDR;  /*!< GPIO port output speed register,       Address offset: 0x08      */
  __IO uint32_t PUPDR;    /*!< GPIO port pull-up/pull-down register,  Address offset: 0x0C      */
  __IO uint32_t IDR;      /*!< GPIO port input data register,         Address offset: 0x10      */
  __IO uint32_t ODR;      /*!< GPIO port output data register,        Address offset: 0x14      */
  __IO uint16_t BSRRL;    /*!< GPIO port bit set/reset low register,  Address offset: 0x18      */
  __IO uint16_t BSRRH;    /*!< GPIO port bit set/reset high register, Address offset: 0x1A      */
  __IO uint32_t LCKR;     /*!< GPIO port configuration lock register, Address offset: 0x1C      */
  __IO uint32_t AFR[2];   /*!< GPIO alternate function registers,     Address offset: 0x20-0x24 */
} GPIO_TypeDef;
```

Does it make sense, for example, to write:

```
((GPIO_TypeDef *) 0x08000) -> MODER = 0x12;
```

I don't get what this line is doing.
It would make more sense to me if you did

```
GPIO_TypeDef * td = 0x08000;
td -> MODER = 0x12;
```

Are these the same? Why?

Comment: `(0x3 << (2*i))` can invoke undefined behaviour. If that is code from ST-examples, I'd be very concerned about the quality of the ST code (but then, I'd not be much surprised). And `MODER` is not "mode reset" (whatever that means), but the GPIO Mode Register. Not clear what your problem is, that is standard C. And that macro does not evaluate to `((GPIO_TypeDef *) 0x0C00)`! You should read the reference manual first.

Comment: I edited it to make it clearer.

Comment: It is nothing more than C programming language manipulation.  The goal is to try to get the compiler to generate specific machine instructions with the right address and data value fed to that instruction.  Using structs is just the latest ghee whiz fad.  Perhaps there is less typing than the prior fads?  Still there is the risk that the compiler doesnt generate the right instruction for you, have seen that happen (but very rare and cant make it happen on demand).  Disassemble the binary and you will see the address and data being pulled into registers then the store in this case happen.

Answer (score 1):

The `GPIO_TypeDef` struct is a clever mechanism for encoding address offsets. So if we are given a pointer to the base GPIOD address and we cast that pointer to a `GPIO_TypeDef` struct pointer, we can use the standard C dereference operator (->) to access an address at some offset from the base GPIOD address.

So in your example, `GPIOD_BASE` evaluates to `(AHB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x0C00)` and `MODER` has an address offset of 0x0 from a `GPIO_TypeDef` struct pointer. This means that `GPIOD_BASE->MODER` evaluates to `(AHB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x0C00) + 0x00`. This is just the address of the port mode register for GPIOD.

This works for all the field defined in the `GPIO_TypeDef` struct. For example, `GPIOD_BASE->PUPDR` evaluates to`(AHB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x0C00) + 0x0C`. This is just the address of the pull-up/pull-down register for GPIOD.

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm happy to edit/clarify this answer if something is wrong or unclear.

Comment: Your text actually says "a `struct` is a clever mechanism to ...". That is basic C and how `struct`s work internally. It is no way specific to this example or embedded programming at all.

Comment: The OP doesn't seem to understand the function of this struct. He said "I don't get what this line is doing." I'm providing general background as well as specific examples of how the expressions OP is asking about are evaluated.

Comment: So thats basically my question- how is a struct evaluated internally?

Comment: An asker can be expected to do basic research. Knowing what a `struct` in C is is part of this. Without this knowledge he will not go anywhere in C programming. We are no tutoring site. This question is actually "what does this code?", which is too broad.

Comment: @ben: See my comment above. Your question will be answered by any good C book. There is a recommendation list on SO, just search for it!

Comment: @ben you may find this site useful for understanding how memory is laid out in structs: http://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-struct-memory-allocation/

Comment: @Olaf Can i rescind this question? Now I realize it was a more basic c question I just realized it when I was dealing with microcontrollers

Comment: I object to the use of the word clever, using structs across compile domains is a recipe for failure, the pointer games without structs to try to get the compiler go generate the right instruction is risky enough.  Using structs across compile domains which is not against the standard or anything, it is just one of those things that ends up having a lifetime of maintenance.  Using it to try to generate specific addresses to feed to specific instructions, rather than just typing those address, that are not going to change in the hardware, is just more typing causing more risk.

Comment: Not clever but some other choice words describe that approach.